# Kubernetes Config Map reload issue

Tags: kubernetes, configmap, dynamic-loading

I am having Kubernetes Config map in spring boot project and My application should dynamically get the values from config map if any values changes in config map so for that I have used spring cloud kubernetes config like below in bootstarp.yml file

```
spring:
  profiles: dev, preprod
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      reload:
        enabled: true
      config:
        enabled: true
        sources:
          - namespace: ${kubernetesnamespace}
            name: ${configmapname}
```

After deploying the application , If I go and change the config map value I am able to get in application without restart which is expected but If I change the config map value after 1 hour of deployment this new value of config map is not reflecting in application but same I f do after 5 mins of deployment it is working.
So what could be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

> what could be the reason

My first suspect would be the application itself. That probably "watches" for the ConfigMap (opens a long-living connection, subscribing for changes on that object). Eventually, those connections may close, which is normal/expected (container restart, etcd leader changes, SDN issues, ...).

I would make sure my application properly acknowledges those and re-connects to the API.

Answer (score 0):

For reload to work, the classes candidate for reloading are needed to be annotated with `@RefreshScope.`

> Please see documentation reference:
> https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-kubernetes/docs/current/reference/html/#propertysource-reload

Notice that default reload strategy is "`refresh`" and whole context is not reloaded unless specified. I hope that helps.